# How does one move html elements with scroll?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create scroll behavior like what can be found [here](http://www.appmiral.com/). If you scroll down the page you will notice the crabs, sharks, waves etc are animated whenever the page moves. How can this be achieved? Is this a script or CSS animation?

Edit: text bubbles also appear and disappear at different scroll points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like a more robust jQuery script to help you out: Per the answer at [Loading a long page with multiple backgrounds based on vertical scroll value in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6658432/2291):

> A slightly more full fat solution to the already great one suggested
>   by Justin is to use [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) to manage the in viewport events.
>
> ...

(the answer by [Nicholas Evens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850319/nicholas-evans))

Answer (score 3):

It is a script, just bind a function to the window 'scroll' event with a callback function to do whatever you want.  You can tell how far you've scrolled with window.scrollY.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    console.log(window.scrollY);
});
```

Comment: how browser intensive is this solution? I'm running `if (window.scrollY > 1700)` then animate a div into the frame.

Answer (score 2):

You need to subscribe `scroll` event using jQuery and move your element basing on the scrolling offset whitch can be reached using `.scrollTop()` property

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    var scrollOffset = $(this).scrollTop();
    // move element to the offcet
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at the site's source code, but I believe it depends on JS. Javascript is necessary to listen to the scroll event of the page, and act according to the current value of `document.scrollTop`. Then the elements can be positioned with JS, and images can be switched either directly in JS, or by using CSS to change some element's CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

That is definitly a script, you can attach an onscroll event and get the percentage of the current scroll and just position your "crabs" depending on that.

There was already a lot of scripts of how to get the percentage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387136/cross-browser-method-to-determine-vertical-scroll-percentage-in-javascript)